# How to use a native latex font and a custom font together

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I would like to use both LaTeX-native fonts for mathematical expressions and a custom font (e.g., Helvetica) exclusively for tick labels in Matplotlib. Setting `text.usetex: True` allows me to use LaTeX fonts for math. However, it also affects tick labels, and the latex font is a bit illegible in the plots. Is there a workaround or a way to use LaTeX fonts for math and a custom font for tick labels simultaneously in Matplotlib?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import numpy as np

font_path = "/path/to/font/Helvetica/Helvetica.ttf"
font_prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=font_path)

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = font_prop.get_name()

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\widetilde{\xi}$', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax.set_xlim([0, 6])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_title('Need Helvetica for Tick Labels in Latex Plot')

plt.show()
```